# Error routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I make sending email with nodemailer library, I am using email office. I already success send email but but it goes to spam email and untrust. can anyone help me?

```
const mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  auth: {
    user: email_user,
    pass: email_pass,
  },
  host: 'mail.***.co.id',
  port: 587,
  secure: true,
});
```